# Digitizing topographic contours to produce DEM from it using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, contour, digitizing

I have four topographic maps spanning 60 years all of which have the same scale (1:62,500). I have digitized contours (5 feet interval, 4 contours 285, 290, 295 and 300 feet) of the same section in each map with the intention of ultimately producing DEM's from them.

I intend to estimate the change in elevation of the surface in this 60 year time period using ArcMap 10.7.1. I am using the "Topo to Raster" tool in the Spatial Analyst tool. Each time I select the individual digitized contours the default output cell size is different.

Could anyone provide insights about why the software is doing this?

Also, I can manually change the output cell size.

What the cell size should I use?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/3d-analyst/topo-to-raster.htm

> If nothing is specified, the cell size is calculated from the shorter
> of the width or height of the extent divided by 250, in which the
> extent is in the Output Coordinate System specified in the
> environment.

Otherwise, it's picked up from a specified existing raster dataset or value, or environment setting.

Just to note, you may want to set the snap raster environment so all your rasters are snapped to each other.

Comment: I am using the Spatial Analyst not the 3D Analyst, also if I output DEM with different default output cell sizes, would they be comparable?

Comment: I believe it's the same tool just offered in both extensions. Either way, the spatial analyst documentation has the same info as the one I linked above. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/topo-to-raster.htm

Generally, it's better to compare rasters that snapped to each other and have the same cell size. But I will differ to others with more experience for a definitive answer.